# Azure APIM IP filter blocks developer portal

Tags: azure-api-management, policy

Applying an IP filter policy in APIM blocks requests from the developer portal. Is there a way to allow developer portal requests with IP filter policy?

Here is the policy I used in the inbound section. The second IP is the Virtual IP (VIP) address of the Gateway, which is the same when running nslookup of developer portal URL.

```
<ip-filter action="allow">
        <address>13.**.**.72</address>
        <address>20.2**.***.158</address>
    </ip-filter>
```

Here is the screenshot of response when testing the API from Developer portal.[image]

Comment: Please share the policy you tried and also share the screenshot how you are trying to access it

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin edited the post.

Comment: Are you getting successful result while testing in portal?

Comment: It wasn't a success initially, but then I added the IP 13.91.254.72 to the allowed list and it worked from the Azure portal. Ref https://mikestephenson.me/2021/01/23/azure-apim-ip-filter-and-testing-from-the-azure-portal/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to allow developer portal requests with IP filter policy?

In order to send the requests with **`ip-filter`** policy from Developer Portal, add `X-Forwarded-For` IP in the policy.

```xml
<ip-filter action="allow">
    <address>x-Forwarded-For IP</address>
</ip-filter>
```

You can get the value of  `X-Forwarded-For` in the trace of any success response.

[image]

After adding it in my policy, I am getting successful result.

[image]

Comment: @Iktesam Thanks! that works. In fact, it is the public IP of the developer portal user.